# Xcode 6 app for different scren sizes

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I write app which is for iPhone 5 screen size. How view controllers can be running in full screen in another devices, such as:IPhone 6,iPhone 6Plus,iPhone 4s. Also I add load image, but it didn't help me. So what I can do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create image assets with the appropriate resolutions and PPI. Then import then with the same file name. But adding @2x for retina 4inch, iphone 5 and iphone 6 . 
@3x for the iphone 6.

For eg. Background.png, background@2x.png, etc.

Use the initial name background.png in the code for this case. The compiler knows which file it should use for which device.

Comment: I must make this pictures in every ViewController I have ImageView?

Comment: Every picture needs to be done at 2x and 3x. But you can reuse them how many ever times you want once ported into the project